# Cash register allowing all coins

Tags: java, beginner

I had to build a cash register that included a `Coin` class that allowed for all types of coins to be used. Please note that for this, no control structures can be used and no data structures such as arrays, lists, and what not. Any constructive criticism is welcome.

```
public class CashRegisterTest
{
    //Test the methods in CashRegister class
    //@param args not used
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //European Coins
        final double EURO = 1;
        final double FIFTY_CENT = .5;
        final double TWENTY_CENT = .2;
        final double TEN_CENT = .1;
        final double FIVE_CENT = .05;
        final double ONE_CENT = .01;

        //American Coins
        final double DOLLAR = 1;
        final double QUARTER = 0.25;
        final double DIME = 0.10;
        final double NICKEL = 0.05;
        final double PENNY = 0.01;

        CashRegister register = new CashRegister();
        register.recordPurchase(10.99);
        register.recordPurchase(10.01);
        register.enterPayment(20, new Coin(EURO));
        register.enterPayment(2, new Coin(FIFTY_CENT));

        System.out.println(register.returnChange());

        CashRegister registerTwo = new CashRegister();
        registerTwo.recordPurchase(10.99);
        registerTwo.recordPurchase(10.01);
        registerTwo.enterPayment(20, new Coin(DOLLAR));
        registerTwo.enterPayment(4, new Coin(QUARTER));

        System.out.println(register.returnChange());
    }
}
```

```
public class CashRegister
{
    private double purchase;
    private double payment;

    private int items;

    //Construct a cash register with no money.
    public CashRegister()
    {
        payment = 0;
        purchase = 0;
        items = 0;
    }

    //Records the purchase price of an item
    //@param amount the price of the purchased item
    public void recordPurchase(double amount)
    {
        purchase += amount;
        items++;
    }

    //Enter payment recieved.
    //@param amount the amount of coins given
    //@param value the coin that has been given.
    public void enterPayment(int amount, Coin value)
    {
        payment += amount * value.getValue();
    }

    //Compute the change due and set the machine for the next customer.
    //@return change the amount due to the customer.
    public double returnChange()
    {
        return payment - purchase;
    }

    //Get the item count
    //@return items the amount of items in this transaction
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return items;
    }
}
```

```
public class Coin
{
    private double value;

    public Coin(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically speaking, American currency has half-dollar coins too.  They're not common, but they are still officially produced and in circulation presently.

Answer (score 7):

You really shouldn't use `double` for currency. It's probably fine for this, but in a real world application, [the accuracy problems you'd experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) would be terrible to deal with. It's recommended that you use the [currency class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) for money.

---

Also, just a small note. I like your brace style, but most Java folks use a different convention. Consistency within a code base is *most* important, but folks get kind of crazy about this kind of trivial stuff. Best to do as the Romans when in Rome.

```
public Coin(double value){
    this.value = value;
}
```

Comment: I didn't even notice the brace style, I'm so used to C#

Comment: IDEs should enforce a standard. There is no good reason why devs have to spend any significant percentage of their time dealing with code formatting issues

Comment: The currency class stores metadata about a currency (eg symbol, number of decimal places); not actual amounts of currency.  IF you're minimizing 3rd party library use, you'd want to use the `BigDecimal` class to store your values in.  If 3rd party lobs are OK, there's Joda Money. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app

Answer (score 6):

The `CashRegister` should be handling a `Purchase` - that's another class. As written your `CashResgister` is a purchase, it is not a cash register. This is because there are class-level variables for a *single* `purchase` and `payment`. A CR should hold a list of all the items bought.

When I go shopping I buy an item. I don't buy a `purchase`. But my "Purchase" is an item + its price.

A "Cash Register" records the purchase object, handles the money transaction, calculates change, taxes, updating inventory counts perhaps (as suggested by the `items` property).

Another CashRegister function is end of day reconciliation. I mean simply adding up all the `purchase.Price`, `purchase.Tax` collected, and clearing it's memory to get ready for the next day.

Even if you cannot have a `List<Purchase>` (list of purchases), your CR should have a `Purchase` object, not separate properties. Use objects.

Answer (score 4):

**class or enum**

This may be out of scope of you're assignment, however it's worth considering using an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) rather than a class to represent the different coins.

**Currency**

As it stands, you're representing coins from different currencies, however the coin only has a value, it doesn't have a currency associated with it.  Similarly the cashregister doesn't take the currency of the coins into account.

**Naming**

Naming often suprisingly hard.  It is however also important for making your code easier to read.

Generally, try to name things for what they represent, not what you're interested in about them.  Consider this code:

```
public void enterPayment(int amount, Coin value)
{
    payment += amount * value.getValue();
}
```

You're passing in a coin, not a value, naming it as such gets rid of the nasty `value.getValue`.

```
public void enterPayment(int amount, Coin coint)
{
    payment += amount * coin.getValue();
}
```

**Change**

Return change is returning the value of the change to be paid.  Given the way payment was made, this feels wrong.  It feels like it should perhaps be returning the coins that would make up the change.  This would be a pain without using control structures, however you could do it by returning a coin at a time and subtracting the coin's value, until the changeDue was 0.

**Reset**

Your comment on `returnChange` says:

> Compute the change due and set the machine for the next customer.

You do the computation, however you don't reset the machine ready for the next customer.  It seems like this should be zero'ing out the currentPurchase, items, purchase (and possibly adding it to a totalPurchases etc variables).  Since it doesn't reset, you're currently having to create a new CashRegister for each transaction.

Comment: Possibly you might want to rename returnChange into a endTransaction and add a getCurrentBalance function